# Динамическое условие в C#

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Можно ли реализовать динамические условия в if?

Т.е юзер вводит какое-то условие типа i>1 и оно подставляется в определенный if при выполнении программы.

Comment: Compiling C# Code at Runtime - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: Можно использовать какой-нибудь скриптовый язык в C#, наподобие IronPython, CS-Script и т. д.

Comment: По CS-Script есть где-нибудь информация на русском? Попытался нагуглить и одни статьи про скрипты в игре Counter-strike...

Comment: Может я и не прав, но если немного переменных может оказаться слева от знака, я бы просто распарсил условие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой способ - использовать [Scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) компилятора:

Подключить пакет Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting -Pre
```

И можно на ходу скриптовать код на C#:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public int i;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // вводится пользователем
            string expression = Console.ReadLine(); // "i > 1";

            var globals = new Globals { i = 2 };

            if (CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(expression, globals: globals).Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False :(");
            }
        }
    }
}
```